# Reversing 'a list list -> 'b list list but getting pattern matching is not exhaustive

Tags: sml

This assignment is from `Induction to Programming using sml 5.14`

Here is my code but I get this message pattern matching is not exhaustive in in base case..

```
fun revrev [] = [[], []]
  | revrev [x::xs,y::ys] = revrev[ys@[y], xs @ [x]];


val test1revrev = revrev [[1, 2],[3, 4, 5]];

From valtest1 I want the output [[5, 4, 3], [2, 1]]
```

I fail to see why my function doesn't work and need a little insight maybe.

For instance this works...

```
fun rev [] = []
  | rev (x::xs) = rev1 xs @ [x];

val test1rev = rev [1, 2, 3];
I get [3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern matching isn't exhaustive because you only match either empty list or list with two elements.

I think the intention of the exercise is to implement `revrev` based on `rev` which has been introduced before. Here are a few tips:

- The base case is empty list. You simply return an empty list.
- The inductive case matches a non-empty list `x::xs`. Similar to implementation of `rev`, you can call `revrev` on `xs` and put a transformation of `x` at the end. This time you need to use `rev` so that `x` itself is also reversed.

**EDIT:**

Your function doesn't work in general cases. What I meant is the following skeleton:

```
fun revrev [] = []
  | revrev (x::xs) = ...
```

where `x` is also a list. Since this function is very similar to `rev`, I hope that you can fill in `...` by yourself.

Comment: Those extra hints was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it finally... Was giving up since it "seemed" advanced but when the code is actually made its simple enough to understand. Thx again.

```
fun rev [] = []
  | rev (x::xs) = rev xs @ [x];

val test1rev1 = rev [1, 2, 3] = [3, 2, 1];


fun revrev [] = [] 
  | revrev (x::xs) = revrev xs @ [rev x];

val test1revop = revop [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]] = [[5, 4, 3], [2, 1]];
```